# Dynamically assign a property in a new statement

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to assign the property subdecision_typex_value which is a property of the class DtoReport using a foreach loop inside a new statement.

Is that possible somehow ? Does it make sense ?

```
public DtoReport Get(Report repResp)
   return new DtoReport()
   {
      archivingId = repResp.archivingId.ToString(),
      dateCreated = DateTime.Now,

      //I'D LIKE TO DO IT THAT WAY IS IT POSSIBLE SOMEHOW ?
      foreach(Subdecision d in repResp.decisionMatrix.subdecisions){
         if(d.type == "SOME VALUE"){
            //Dynamically assign DtoReport subdecision_typex_value Property 
            subdecision_typex_value = d.value                   
         }
      }
      //END

      anotherProperty = repResp.AnotherProperty
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq:

```
return new DtoReport()
{
  archivingId = repResp.archivingId.ToString(),
  dateCreated = DateTime.Now,
  subdecision_typex_value = repResp.decisionMatrix.subdecisions
                           .Where(d => d.type == "SOME VALUE")
                           .Select(d => d.value)
                           .FirstOrDefault(),
  anotherProperty = repResp.AnotherProperty
}
```

Note that your approach most likely does not what it was supposed to do. You're enumerating all subdecisions and then you're taking the last value with `type=="SOME VALUE"`. I assume you want to take the first value of this type, am i right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I didn't figured out that I could use linq for that. Also I don't understand the downvote do you have any idea why I've been downvoted ? Was this question so obvious or already asked ?

Comment: "I didn't figured out that I could use linq for that" means that it's not working for you? I don't know why someone downvoted your answer , maybe because it _"doesn't work"_ is not a good description of a compiler warning or whatelse. Here are some informations how to improve questions: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Yeah it's working ! Thanks ! I just tried it. Also i've just edited the question to remove the "Not working" part which is I admit not appropriate.